# How to fix 'Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device' in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, gpu, lstm

When I want to put the model on the GPU, I get the following error:

> "RuntimeError: Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu"

However, all of the above had been put on the GPU:

```
for m in model.parameters():
    print(m.device) #return cuda:0
```

```py
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
    test = test.cuda() # test is the Input
```

---

Windows 10 server
Pytorch 1.2.0 + cuda 9.2
cuda 9.2
cudnn 7.6.3 for cuda 9.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running LSTM with multiple GPUs gets "Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511769/running-lstm-with-multiple-gpus-gets-input-and-hidden-tensors-are-not-at-the-sa)

Comment: you need to send your inputs also to cuda. so for example your X_train_batch and label_batch etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to move the model, the inputs, and the targets to Cuda:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
   model.cuda()
   inputs = inputs.cuda() 
   target = target.cuda()
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when PyTorch tries to compute an operation between a tensor stored on a CPU and one on a GPU. At a high level there are two types of tensor - those of your data, and those of the parameters of the model, and both can be copied to the same device like so:

```py
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

data = data.to(device)
model = model.to(device)
```

Comment: Just a minor edit, there is no need to reassign model after putting it on the GPU; this might actually result in an error. Simply write ```model.to(device)```.