# I meet a problem which is "RuntimeError: Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu"

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I guess the hidden tensor is the tenor which I need to initialize in the beginning of RNN. So I set the h0 and c0 by .cuda(), but that is not useful. Following is my code.Please, who can give me a hand?

```
class LSTM_net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, Embedding, vocab, label, batch):
    super(LSTM_net, self).__init__()
    self.Hidden_dim = Embedding
    self.Embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab, Embedding)  
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(Embedding, self.Hidden_dim)  # 32 * 32
    self.hidden2label = nn.Linear(Embedding, label)
    self.hidden = self.init_hidden(batch)

def init_hidden(self, batch):  
    # the first is the hidden h
    # the second is the cell c

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, batch, self.Hidden_dim)),
                autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, batch, self.Hidden_dim)))
    else:
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, batch, self.Hidden_dim).cuda()),
                autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, batch, self.Hidden_dim).cuda()))

def forward(self, sentence):
    # 64 * 52
    x = self.Embedding(sentence)
    # x = 64 * 52 * 32
    x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)
    # x = 52 * 64 * 32
    lstm_y, lstm_hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
    # lstm_y = batch * 52 * 32
    # input: lstm_y[-1] = batch * 32
    y = self.hidden2label(lstm_y[-1])
    # y = batch * 5
    log_probs = F.log_softmax(y)
    return log_probs
```

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you are defining an object of `LSTM_net` and training the model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device' in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095627/how-to-fix-input-and-hidden-tensors-are-not-at-the-same-device-in-pytorch)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

initially I thought you did the error of not putting .cuda() before wrapping it in the variable like it is described here:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tensor-cuda-vs-variable-cuda/12549

However, you have correctly converted it while initializing and wrapped it in the variable. Your small mistake is with your loop. In your **if statement**, when you **are using** GPU, you **don't** activate cuda but instead when it's in the else loop. With or without GPU it'll fail.

Instead of correcting your if-else, might I suggest you the recommended way of doing by:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class LSTM_net(nn.Module):
    ...
    ...
    def init_hidden(self, batch):  
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, batch, self.Hidden_dim).to(device)),
                autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, batch, self.Hidden_dim).to(device)))
```

Using .to(device) will avoid most of these device errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error might stem from the way your code is executed. You might be facing this issue because you are running this code on a machine with GPUs available that forces the hidden tensor to be a `cuda` tensor. However, while executing in the main code if you give a cpu input tensor pytorch would raise a mismatch error. To prevent this do the change as mentioned below.

```py
def forward(self, sentence):
    # 64 * 52
    x = self.Embedding(sentence)
    # x = 64 * 52 * 32
    x = x.permute(1, 0, 2).cuda() # <----- this change; add if condition to check for GPUs
    # x = 52 * 64 * 32
    lstm_y, lstm_hidden = self.lstm(x, self.hidden)
    # lstm_y = batch * 52 * 32
    # input: lstm_y[-1] = batch * 32
    y = self.hidden2label(lstm_y[-1])
    # y = batch * 5
    log_probs = F.log_softmax(y)
    return log_probs
```