# Torch.cuda.empty_cache() very very slow performance

Tags: pytorch, gpu, inference

I have a **very slow performance** problem when I execute an **inference batch loop** on a single GPU.

This slow behavior appears **after the first batch** has been processed -
that is when the GPU is already almost full and its memory needs to be recycled to accept the next batch.

At a **pristine** GPU state - the performance is **super fast** (as expected).

I hope both the following code snippet and the output illustrate the problem in a nutshell.

(*I've removed the print and time measurements from the snippet for brevity*)

```
predictions = None

for i, batch in enumerate(self.test_dataloader):

    # if this line is active - the bottleneck after the first batch moves here, rather than below
    # i.e. when i > 0
    # torch.cuda.empty_cache()    

    # HUGE PERFORMANCE HIT HAPPENS HERE - after the first batch
    # i.e. when i > 0
    # obviously tensor.to(device) uses torch.cuda.empty_cache() internally when needed
    # and it is inexplicably SLOW
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)  # to GPU (or CPU) when gpu

    b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask)

    logits = outputs[0]
    logits = logits.detach()

    # that doesn't help alleviate the issue
    del outputs

    predictions = logits if predictions is None else torch.cat((predictions, logits), 0)            

    # nor do all of the below - freeing references doesn't help speeding up
    del logits
    del b_input_ids
    del b_input_mask
    del b_labels
    for o in batch:
        del o
    del batch
```

output

```
start empty cache... 0.00082
end empty cache... 1.9e-05
start to device... 3e-06
end to device... 0.001179 - HERE - time is super fast (as expected)
start outputs... 8e-06
end outputs... 0.334536
logits... 6e-06
start detach... 1.7e-05
end detach... 0.004036

start empty cache... 0.335932
end empty cache... 4e-06
start to device... 3e-06
end to device... 16.553849 - HERE - time is ridiculously high - it's 16 seconds to move tensor to GPU
start outputs... 2.3e-05
end outputs... 0.020878
logits... 7e-06
start detach... 1.4e-05
end detach... 0.00036

start empty cache... 0.00082
end empty cache... 6e-06
start to device... 4e-06
end to device... 17.385204 - HERE - time is ridiculously high
start outputs... 2.9e-05
end outputs... 0.021351
logits... 4e-06
start detach... 1.3e-05
end detach... 1.1e-05

...
```

Have I missed something obvious or is this the **expected** GPU behavior?

I am posting this question before engaging in complex coding, juggling between a couple of GPUs and CPU available on my server.

Thanks in advance,
Albert

#### EDIT

**RESOLVED** The issue was: in `DataLoader` constructor - I changed the `pin_memory to False` (*True* was causing the issue). That cut the `.to(device)` time by 350%-400%

```
self.test_dataloader = DataLoader(
            test_dataset,
            sampler=SequentialSampler(test_dataset),
            # batch_size=len(test_dataset)  # AKA - single batch - nope! no mem for that
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_AKA_MAX_ROWS_PER_GUESS_TO_FIT_GPU_MEM,
            # tests
            num_workers=8,
            # maybe this is the culprit as suggested by user12750353 in stackoverflow
            # pin_memory=True
            pin_memory=False
        )
```

Comment: As you already confirmed elsewhere, the cost of `cudaFree()` is fairly high and about the order of magnitude of the cost of `cudaMalloc()`. In absolute terms I observe between 2 and 10 microseconds per `cudaFree()` across various hardware and software environments. The slow speed of `cudaFree()` has been well-known for many years. The fact that there haven't been substantial changes *suggests* underlying technical issues that cannot be changed. The workaround is to avoid frequent allocation and de-allocation of GPU memory and to hold on to and re-use existing allocations as much as possible.

Comment: thanks, so my intuition was right - I have no way of avoiding de-allocation, since the GPU is full after the first round and .to(device) does the de-allocation or `empty_cache()` internally.

So I guess it's get-my-hands-dirty coding time - keep track of if GPU is free or `empty_cache()` in progress, and during `empty_cache()` time do calculations on **CPU**...

Any idea if such a solution/library might already exist?

Comment: I don't use PyTorch, and don't understand when and why it flushes caches with `empty_cache()`. I would *assume* that PyTorch developers are aware of the slow speed of GPU memory allocation *and de-allocation* and have structured their code accordingly. From a generic programming viewpoint, flushing caches should not be necessary within a single run of an application. The answer below seems to suggest the same. Maybe there are relevant configuration settings that you could explore? Consider asking for help using the PyTorch support channel (a mailing list or forum, presumably).

Comment: I don't think my use case is extraordinary. I just have to do real time inference (classifying) on a relatively large number of inputs - sometimes a couple of thousands sometimes several hundred thousands. An average of 20K. So I have no way other than flushing caches, since I have a single GPU (since I am not Google or Facebook, having unlimited resources and don't have 16 or 32 modern GPUs to run inference in parallel on).

Comment: Just out of curiosity - from a C/C++ perspective - why would malloc, or rather the opposite of it - freeing the allocated memory take forever? I am almost certain (without being a driver low level expert) - this is not the case on regular RAM chips. Why would it be so drastically different on a GPU?

Comment: This is not a forum for discussions, so I will stop after this message. [1] I made (and make) no claims as to whether your use case is typical of PyTorch usage. I simply suggested to take up PyTorch performance issues with the PyTorch developers. [2] I have no knowledge of GPU memory allocators. However, if it involves any communication with the GPU across the PCIe interconnect, the basic latency of that (on the order of a microsecond, I think) could explain the performance. The latency of the CPU communicating with system RAM is on the order of 90 nanoseconds.

Comment: thanks, that helps me a lot actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be required to clear cache if you are properly clearing the references to the previously allocated variables. Cache is like free, is memory that your script can use for new variables.

Also notice that

```py
a = torch.zeros(10**9, dtype=torch.float)
a = torch.zeros(10**9, dtype=torch.float)
```

Requires 8GB of memory, even though a uses 4GB (1B elements with 4 bytes each). This occurs because the `torch.zeros` will allocate memory before the previous content of `a` is released. This may be happening in your model in a larger scale, depending on how it is implemented.

**Edit 1**

One suspicious thing is that you are loading your batch to the GPU one example at a time.

Just to illustrate what I mean

```py
import torch
device = 'cuda'
batch = torch.zeros((4500, 10));
```

Creating the batch as a tuple

```py
batch_gpu = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch) 
torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

254 ms ± 36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Creating the batch as a list

```py
batch_gpu = list(t.to(device) for t in batch) 
torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

235 ms ± 3.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```py
batch_gpu = batch.to(device)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

115 µs ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In this example it was 2000x faster to copy one example at a time.

Notice that GPU works asynchronously with the CPU. So you may keep calling functions that will return before the operation is finished. In order to make meaningful measurements you may call [synchronize](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.synchronize) to make clear the time boundaries.

The code to be instrumented is this

```py
for i, batch in enumerate(self.test_dataloader):

    # torch.cuda.empty_cache()    
    # torch.synchronize() # if empty_cache is used
    

    # start timer for copy
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)  # to GPU (or CPU) when gpu
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    # stop timer for copy

    b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch

    # start timer for inference
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask)
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    # stop timer for inference


    logits = outputs[0]
    logits = logits.detach()
    # if you copy outputs to CPU it will be synchronized
```

Comment: I've edited my original post - the sample snippet there includes deleting all references possible - which has no effect (as expected)

Comment: What is the type of your batch??

Comment: it's text (titles, e.g. Nike running shoes for women), encoded using hugging-face transformers encode_plus(). My model was fine-tuned on bert large uncased. It's an NLP classifier, having a little less than 5K classes. The original notebook I've used for training and inference is this: http://mccormickml.com/2019/07/22/BERT-fine-tuning/#52-evaluate-on-test-set

Comment: I asked because maybe I don't know if it supports .to directly on the batch.

Comment: thanks, sounds promising - will test later and post results

Comment: not working - issue remains
<br>
the batch actually contains just 3 elements: 
<br>
`b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch`
<br>
changing from tuple to list has no time gain
<br>
it looks like a GPU - PCI communication latency as suggested by @njuffa
<br>
I'll contact indeed the pytorch forums to check if it's related to their implementation (which I am skeptic about)
<br>
anyway, thanks @njuffa and @user12750353 for your help, deeply appreciated

Comment: Are you using `torch.cuda.synchronize()` before stopping your timer? Otherwise the fast execution on the first iteration may be because the operation was deferred. Updating the post to make explicit that I used this method in the measurements.

Comment: yes, I tried also `torch.cuda.synchronize()` - the first batch is always fast. If I do just a single batch and then use the predictions on GPU, without moving to CPU - I don't have to hit the `torch.cuda.synchronize()` or `empty_cache` bottleneck

Comment: And what if instead of copying a new batch you simply shuffle the existing batch and process it again.

Comment: I'll try that and let know

Comment: I am having trouble shuffling/re-indexing a pytorch tensor already on the GPU memory. I am trying `tensor = tensor.view` and `tensor = tensor[shuffled_indices]`. Both results are not on GPU. Do you have an example of how to shuffle on GPU without round-tripping to CPU?

Comment: `tensor[torch.randperm(tensor.shape[0], device=tensor.device)]`, if the axis 0 is the one indexed by example

Comment: unable to shuffle tensors on GPU - *RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device* - shuffled tensors are not on GPU. Getting this error when calling: `outputs = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask)`. `b_input_ids` and `b_input_mask` have been shuffled

Comment: Have you moved your `model.to(device)`? There should be no indices here. As far as I know the shuffled tensor is contiguous. And the argument `device=tensor.device` to `randperm`, should ensure the data to be on the same device as it was before.
You can try to be more explicit about that `tensor[...] = tensor[torch.randperm(tensor.shape[0], device=tensor.device), ...]`. But maybe the error is related to something on your model. See this for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095627/how-to-fix-input-and-hidden-tensors-are-not-at-the-same-device-in-pytorch

Comment: Sure, model is on cuda. Otherwise first batch wouldn't have worked. Explicit `tensor[...]` made no difference. `device=tensor.device` used in `randperm`  Error *RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device* remains. Currently unable to shuffle tensor already on GPU

Comment: Your situation is definitely very intriguing. Can you share a complete notebook to reproduce it?

Comment: it'll take me some time to prepare one - since there are credentials and proprietary stuff which I can't disclose in the one I am using. Will post when I have it

Comment: Maybe during the preparation you eliminate the problem by your self. But now I am intrigued with this hehe

Comment: **RESOLVED** - user12750353 you were right - I found the culprit while preparing the project for a public notebook. The issue was: in `DataLoader` constructor - I changed the `pin_memory to False` (*True* was causing the issue). That cut the `.to(device)` time by **350%-400%**. Thanks again for your cooperation. Following is the notebook:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iHAXy_mYKMOBgtrZ4o2CIo6ngE_JVTR4?usp=sharing . I'll let know the author of the tutorial my code was based on about the inference issue (Chris McCormick)